# Css não funcionando no firefox

Tags: css

Tenho um progress bar que tem algum estilos nele.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz alguns ajustes nele, como colocar border radius e adicionei texto dentro do progress bar.
O problema é que quando eu visualizo esse progress bar no Firefox por algum motivo não funciona. Como posso corrigir isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
progress {
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
  width: 70px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 80px;
  /* Set the progressbar to relative */
  position: relative;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: white;
}

progress:before {
  content: attr(data-label)" %";
  font-size: 0.8em;
  vertical-align: 0;
  border-radius: 80px;
  /*Position text over the progress bar */
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: #c9c9c9;
  border-radius: 80px;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: #7CB342;
  border-radius: 80px;
}

progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background-color: #7CB342;
}
```

```html
<progress data-label="83" />
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Fatou somente o "border-radius: 80px;" no "progress::-moz-progress-bar", que é o que justamente define o estilo do progressbar para o firefox.

```css
progress {
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
  width: 70px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 80px;
  /* Set the progressbar to relative */
  position: relative;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: white;
}

progress:before {
  content: attr(data-label)" %";
  font-size: 0.8em;
  vertical-align: 0;
  border-radius: 80px;
  /*Position text over the progress bar */
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: #c9c9c9;
  border-radius: 80px;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: #7CB342;
  border-radius: 80px;
}

progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background-color: #7CB342;
  border-radius: 80px;
}
```

```html
<progress data-label="83" />
```

Comment: Faltava isso mesmo, mas ainda está faltando o texto do content: attr(data-label)" %";
Sabe o que pode ser? O que mostra o 83% por exemplo, igual ao chrome por exemplo

Comment: Poxa amigo, a função attr() pode ser utilizada com qualquer propriedade CSS, mas o suporte para propriedades que não sejam content é experimental no firefox, de acordo com o seguinte link: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/attr(). Sugiro utilizar um JS para manipular o resultado, deixando o content vazio.

Comment: Os navegadores são API e estamos limitados às implementações deles, nem sempre dá pra fazer tudo o que desejamos... mas tem formas de contornar isso, utilizando o valor entre as tags progress e atualizar via JS mesmo, selecionando o elemento e setando o texto (innerText).

Comment: Até desanima sugerir alguma coisa, pois tudo no stack o povo negativa... ultimamente (nos últimos anos) a galerinha só sabe fazer isso...

Comment: "Sugiro utilizar um JS para manipular o resultado". É porque a minha aplicação é em angular. Mas muito obrigado pelo apoio aí e as respostas, já consigo me virar aqui

Comment: "Até desanima sugerir alguma coisa, pois tudo no stack o povo negativa.". Infelizmente é assim, eu desanimo tbm, só fiz essa pergunta porque eu realmente não tava tendo outra opção. Mas é complicado msm